# How to display data from a table in SSMS into an Angular project?

Tags: sql-server, angular, ssms

I am new to Angular and web development.

So basically, I have to display data from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio which I can obtain through a query on a web page (using Angular).

The problem is that the size of the data is very large and as such, it is too tedious to copy paste each element of the table into the html file (for the Angular project).

I was wondering if there was any way of directly transferring the desired data from Microsoft SSMS to the html file of my Angular project?

Sorry about the lack of specific details. The data is confidential and as such, cannot be displayed here.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SSMS as Database and Angular in front end.
Then you should use dotnet core web api as a backend.
Which will take the data from DB and leave it at the endpoint.

Then from that endpoint you have to connect your Angular Project and retreive all the information using HTTP Services.

Watch this video tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fom80TujpYQ

Weather it is one record and crores of records you have to go through this process.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per your question:

> I was wondering if there was any way of directly transferring the desired data from Microsoft SSMS to the html file of my Angular project?

Answer is No. You must retrieve data from `SSMS` table into `Angular` through the `REST` services which you have to develop in, for example, `.NET`.

So, you need to use a backend technology, like `.Net Core Web API` to expose some backend services, like REST services then use `Angular` to request them for data in `SSMS` table.

Data retrieval mechanism is something like this:

> Angular HttpClient services <=> .NET Core Web API/REST services <=> MSSQL Server/SSMS Database